# How can I send image to other user by using firebase and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, cloud

I am new to firebase and I am trying to send image to other users in group. But I can't find correct way to do it...
I want display image with it's src stored in database how to do that?

```
fuction sendImage(){

    if (snpVal.msg.indexOf("base64") !== -1) {
        const dbbbb = db.ref(`WebApp/Web Devs/chatMessages/${chtMainMsg.id}`).push({imageSrc: snpVal.msg});
        const dbmsg = db.ref(`WebApplication/Web Devs/chatMessages/`).child(`${snpVal.chgId}`);

        dbmsg.update({msg: ''});

        let imgElm = document.createElement("img");
        let br = document.createElement("br");

        imgElm.src = snpVal.imageSrc;


        chtMainMsg.innerText = dbmsg;

        chtTxt.appendChild(imgElm);
        chtTxt.appendChild(br);

        if (chtMainMsg.innerText === snpVal.msg) chtMainMsg.innerText = '';

    }

}
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

think the best way would be to store the link in the firebase database service, and query for the value of desired links